# How to excess image control in server side in asp.net app?

Tags: html, asp.net

How to excess 'imginfo' in the server side?Please help.I have to hide the image if the login info does not match.

Comment: So, do you want to hide the image if the data has certain value in it, right?

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I am trying to check if the data has a certain value and if no, then then I wanna hide that image.Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want to hide the image if certain data has certain value. You, can simply compare the value and apply a `css` class as hidden to that element like:

First, add this `css` in the `head` element.

```
.d-none {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Then replace your image control with this markup:

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="imgInfo" CssClass='<%# Eval("SomeColumn") == DBNull.Value ? "d-none" : "" %>' ImageUrl="~/Images/info-note.png" tooltip='<%# Eval("user_address").ToString().Trim() %>' style="position: center; top: 3px; padding-right: 3px; padding-left:5px;cursor: help;" />
```

You can replace `SomeColumn` with the database column that contains your value to be compared and I just compared if it was null, you can do other comparisons as well.

**UPDATE**

You can add another clause in the comparison and we can use `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` method to check if the `varchar` column is empty.

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="imgInfo" CssClass='<%# Eval("SomeColumn") == DBNull.Value || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("SomeColumn").ToString()) ? "d-none" : "" %>' ImageUrl="~/Images/info-note.png" tooltip='<%# Eval("user_address").ToString().Trim() %>' style="position: center; top: 3px; padding-right: 3px; padding-left:5px;cursor: help;" />
```

Comment: Thank you@Jamshaid Kamran. The database column that needs to be compared is of type varchar. I have to compare if it is null or empty or has any value. Does DBNull include both null or empty check?like in server side we can achieve it doing:  if(String.IsNullorEmpty()){ //make invisible code}

Comment: @Osheca, It will only check if you have `NULL` in your database column. See the update in my answer for the empty comparison.

Comment: that's what I was looking for. Thanks a lot @Jamshaid Kamran.

Comment: @Osheca Make sure to accept the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: can you please help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64705825/javascript-code-snippet-not-working-in-google-chrome-but-works-in-ie

Answer (score 1):

You can access the control at a row level in the function given to OnItemDataBound of the list view.

```
protected void lvLoginDetails_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Item is ListViewDataItem)
  {
     ImageButton imb = (ImageButton)e.Item.FindControl("imgInfo");
     // ...
  }
}
```

Edit 1

If you want to access it anywhere else you will have to iterate through the listView items like below. Make sure u have bound some data before trying to access the control.

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in lvLoginDetails.Items)
{
    ImageButton imb = (ImageButton)item.FindControl("imgInfo");
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am trying to get it to access from page_load method or lvLoginDetails_BindData() because I am fetching data there and trying to utilizing the same data to check the condition and display or hide that image control. Is it possible to do it?Any ideas?